# how to convert YMD_HMS "character" into date in R

Tags: r, date, lubridate, as.date

I am in R studio trying to separate my dates "6/30/22 17:27" into year, month, day, and hms columns.
The problem is it's not a numeric type variable, it's a character type. So I need to convert it before I can separate it into my needed columns.

So I tried using

```
#convert dates from characters to dates
all_trips$date <- as.Date(all_trips$started_at)
```

but I only got this error message

```
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

so I tried converting to a numeric using as.numeric but only got this

```
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

it only came back as null values.

I tried using the lubridate package to see if I could convert them to mdy_hm but that onyl came back as

```
Warning message:
 3485127 failed to parse.
```

I'm not quite sure what I can do at this point.

Answer (score 0):

this apparently works...

```
all_trips$date <- mdy_hm(all_trips$started_at)
```

... I don't understand what changed but here we are.